# No access to db from Site.Master in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET C# and SQL server

I have created a dynamically build menu in the master page. The menu is a result of a sql query. When i run the page in debug mode with the local sql server there is no problems to get result from the db and the menu is created. But when I run the application on the web server I got no result, no errors. Nothing...

What is wrong?

Comment: paste some code?? tables Structure???

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or exceptions? Can you connect on other pages?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using and where is it located or hosted? Does you server has access to server where your database is? Are you using correct connection string?